# Apache multiviews unexpected behaviour

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have Apache multiviews enabled on my site but it's causing an unexpected behaviour.

my site www.example.com has an images folder like www.example.com/imgs/ where I store all images

so if I have www.example.com/imgs/pic1.jpg there and I try to access it, it's all fine and it shows the image on my browser.

Now if I go ahead and delete pic1.jpg from the imgs folder, and try to access www.example.com/imgs/pic1.jpg again, I was expecting a 404 but somehow I get served the page www.example.com/index.php (although css styling is lost). It's not a redirect, the URL in the address bar still shows www.example.com/imgs/pic1.jpg but loads the script at www.example.com/index.php

I suspect it's something related to multiviews, my htaccess has only the multiviews option. So how can I fix this? And why apache+multiviews would serve the site's index.php script one folder above?

Thanks

Just to mention that a request to www.example.com/script corretly loads www.example.com/script.php

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess?

Comment: It only has: Options +MultiViews and nothing else

Comment: No, the _other_ .htaccess at your top level. And your Apache virtualhost configuration while you're at it.

Comment: @Michael example.com is an addon domain to primarydomain.com which is a shared hosting acct - i'm not sure if you  mean the .htaccess file on the primarydomain.com but here it is `# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress`

Comment: Please edit your question to add the config there instead of in a comment, it's really hard to read without proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what was causing this behaviour. As Michael mentioned, it was the primary domain's .htaccess affecting the add-on domain. In my case the solution was simple because I don't need rewrite rules in the add-on domain directory so I just added a line to the .htaccess file for the add-on domain:

RewriteEngine Off